# tornado websocket closing unexpectedly

Tags: html, websocket, tornado

I can't figure out why socket closes on windows platform.

The following simple server works on my linux box (chrome and firefox), but not on my windows box or android phone where I just see the message "socket closed".  This [chat demo](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py) works find on all the platforms I've tried.  Thanks for any advice.

Justin

---- Server Code:------

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
        self.write_message("Hello World")
        for i in range(3):
            self.write_message('Testing %d' % i)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        self.close()      
    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
      print 'connection closed'

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("logdemo.html")

application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', MainHandler),
        (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    print 'serving on port 8888'
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

---- logdemo.html ----

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function log(m) {
        d = document.getElementById("log");
        d.innerHTML = m + "<br/>" + d.innerHTML;
      }
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var ws = new WebSocket("ws://raspberrypi.local:8888/ws");

      ws.onopen = function(evt) { log("socket opened"); };
      ws.onmessage = function(evt) { log("message: " + evt.data); ws.send("GOTIT");};
      ws.onclose = function(evt) { log("socket closed"); };
      });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Websockets Streaming</h1>
    <div id="log"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On windows platform or in internet explorer?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling self.close() in the open method of the WSHandler.
I believe this is the reason, isn't it?